# UIImagePickerController captureMode not assigning correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController to take pictures and videos from my app. Toggling between the two isn't too bad. If the user chooses to record a video, I first check this:

```
if (picker.cameraCaptureMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo)
{
    [self captureVideo];
}
else
{
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
    [self captureVideo];
}
```

This usually works totally fine. Here's the catch. I'm also using OpenTok by Tokbox to do video calls, and it seems like the captureMode assignment doesn't work after a video call. It seems completely crazy, but I made this modification to do some debugging:

```
if (picker.cameraCaptureMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo)
{
    [self captureVideo];
}
else
{
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
    if (picker.cameraCaptureMode != UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo)
    {
        NSLog(@"Assignment unsuccessful???")
    }
    [self captureVideo];
}
```

And i get this "Assignment unsuccessful???" log every single time. UIImagePickerController must not be allowing the assignment or something. I really can't figure it out. I've also made a forum post on OpenTok's site to see if they're possibly not releasing some camera resources, but I don't think it's their problem.

Any insight here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a solution on the TokBox forum. I needed to first change my audio session before trying to access the microphone.

```
AVAudioSession *mySession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[mySession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:nil];

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
+ (NSArray *)availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice:(UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice)cameraDevice
```

to check which source types are available. Also if you're using a simulator, it will never assign properly.